# Matrix series manipulation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

The exercise asks me to show that (these are all real matrices) the following relation holds:

$$
(A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1} = A^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (BA^{-1})^k$$

I suspect that the question is wrong, since the sum should actually read: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k (BA^{-1})^k$
Justification for stating so:
$$
(A+B)^{-1} = [A(I+BA^{-1})]^{-1} = (I+BA^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}\underbrace{=}_{*}A^{-1}\sum_{\mathbf{k=0}}^\infty (-1)^k (BA^{-1})^k=\\A^{-1}+A^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (BA^{-1})^k \\\implies (A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (BA^{-1})^k
$$

At the step $*$, I suppose I can't commute. Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $A+B = (I+B A^{-1}) A$ instead. And yes, there should be a $(-1)^k$ term. (Plus, you need to know that the spectrum of $B A^{-1}$ lies inside the unit disk.)

Comment: Note $A(I+BA^{-1}) = A + ABA^{-1}$ is in general different from $A+B$.

Comment: What about at $*$, is that valid?

Comment: No. That is why I suggested expanding $A+B$ as above.

Comment: Now I see it, thanks!